# Load jQuery tabs after XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, tabs, xmlhttprequest

I have a Codeigniter site with 3 columns, the first showing a list of ships. When a ship is selected it loads information on the ship to the center column via the controller. I would like to get tabs working on each column loaded as there is a lot of information to hold on each, but they don't load properly. When I click on any of the links it redirects me back to my home page with the #tab-1 id at the end of the url. I have no idea where to go from here.

This is the function called after the onClick for each ship

```
function fleetDetails(ID)
{   
if (ID=="")
{
    document.getElementById("fleet-details").innerHTML="";
    return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("fleet-details").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","admin/manage/fleet_details/?fleet_association_ID="+ID,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

I have tried adding this to the end of the function but the tabs don't seem to work.

```
$('#fleet_tabs').tabs({
    event: "mouseover"
});
```

Am I going about this the completely wrong way? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried adding the code to `$(function() { // your code.. });` instead?

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add you tabs code in the `onreadystatechange` function, like this

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

            document.getElementById("fleet-details").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

            $('#fleet_tabs').tabs({ event: "mouseover" });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I managed to get this working after a lot of trial and error, cheers!